# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\adduser.php on line 42

Tags: javascript, php

What could be the issue?

```
function db(){
        $con= new mysqli('localhost' , 'root','','signupsystem') or die("fail". mysqli_connect_error());

        $queryb="Insert into adduser(name,fathername,gender,address,cnic,contactnumber,email,password) values($this->name,$this->fathername,
                $this->gender,$this->address,$this->cinic_no,$this->contact_n0, $this->email , $this->password)";

         $result = $con->query($queryb);
    if (!$result) {
        die($con->error);
    }
         $stmt = $con->prepare($queryb);

                if($stmt === "false")
                {
                    trigger_error('Wrong Sql:' . $queryb . ' Error ' . $this->con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
                }
                                $stmt->execute();
                $af = $stmt->affected_rows;
        $con->close();
        return $af;

    }
```

Comment: Compare with `false`, not `"false"`.

Comment: after change false that error occour  
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '6110197860375,03414216670, mudassarfuut@gmail.com , )' at line 2"

Comment: Exactly, now take a look at your sql and fix that error.

Comment: thx sir ur answer help me alot

Answer (score 2):

Make these 2 things proper:

```
$queryb="Insert into adduser(name,fathername,gender,address,cnic,contactnumber,email,password) values($this->name,$this->fathername,
            $this->gender,$this->address,$this->cinic_no,$this->contact_n0, $this->email , $this->password)";
```

Strings fields always be concatenated with single quotes like `"'.$this->cinic_no.'"`

and compare it like:

```
if($stmt === false) // not "false"
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir , your answer really help me alot

Comment: @Mudassar no one is sir here. Sounds great that it helps you.